# Meaning of "run its course"in this sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning

The American War of Independence was first viewed by the British as a minor rebellion that would soon run its course.I don't know how to paraphrase 'run its course' in this sentence.

Comment: I have googled,because I googled there are different meanings I don't know which to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To develop in the usual way and come to the usual end.[From the OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/course_1#course_1__178)